# How to refactor gesture detector in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Code before putting in function was working properly, but cause I am going to use it a lot I wanted to refactor it. After pressing the text doesn't give any result. I have done the same with TextFormField and it worked out.

````
    Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, children: <Widget>[
      GestureDetector(
        child: Text(data, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 16)),
        onTap: () => onTap,
      )
    ]);


gestureTextDetector("Hello", ()=> Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginForm()))),```
````

Comment: What do you want to do ? The question is not clear !

Comment: `behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
onTap:(){
onTap
}

gestureTextDetector("Hello",Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginForm()))),
```